# Подключение js и css в зависимости от userAgent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо следующее. Создать проверку на js (проверяем userAgent) + проверка версии.
Пример:

если браузер мазила, то подключаем эти файлы

```
{   
/style.css   
/animation.js   
}   
Если опера, то {   
/style1.css   
/animation1.js    
}   
...   
//здесть другие браузеры для ПК   
...
```

Если пользователь заходит с телефона или планшета

```
{   
/style2.css      
/animation2.js     
}
```

То есть мне нужно, для разных браузеров подключить разные файлы + создать условие, что для всех кто сидит НЕ с пк (для всех телефонов, планшетов ) - подключить другие файлы.
Повторюсь, что проверку принципиально сделать на js.

upd:
 Сложность номер 1 это как внутри  подключить отдельный файл js.Ведь такая конструкция

```
<script><script src=""></script></script>
```

не сработает.
Сложность вторая.Как проверить все телефоны,планшеты и выдать им отдельный файл.Ведь при проверки юзер агента.Пользователь может допустим на телефона установить оперу-тогда как нам понять что он с телефона?!Фильтровать по платформе?!Там далеко не 100% угадаешь.

Comment: а в чем сложность?

Comment: добавьте это описание в сам вопрос

Comment: @Grundy. Добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу добавления: теги script, это такие же элементы *DOM* как и любые другие, а значит вы их можете создать и вставить куда нужно.

например:

```
if(condition){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "path_to_script"
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

По второму пункту:

> Как проверить все телефоны,планшеты и выдать им отдельный файл.Ведь при проверки юзер агента.Пользователь может допустим на телефона установить оперу-тогда как нам понять что он с телефона?!Фильтровать по платформе?!Там далеко не 100% угадаешь.

Никак.
Максимум можно проверить user-agent, который любой браузер может менять как захочет.

Comment: А если сделать так.Сначала проверить размер экрана,если он меньше X значения-то подключаем файлы для мобильников и планшетов.если больше-идет вторая проверка уже по обычному юзер агенту

Comment: @HoPkInS, не очень хорошее решение, сейчас планшеты, да и некоторые телефоны, имеют разрешение сравнимое в обычным монитором. Опять же. откуда вы возьмете `X` по которому будете определять?

Comment: Можно с вами в чате пообщаться?!

Comment: @HoPkInS попробуйте, и вот сайт еще http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ на котором можно скачать регулярку для проверки на мобильный браузер не мобильный

Answer (score 0):

http://javascript.ru/blog/Plush-Grigorij/Funkciya-opredeleniya-brauzera-ego-versii

Вообще, правильнее проверять не сам браузер, а его возможности, что по поводу "для всех телефонов, планшетов" - медиазапросы в помощь.

Comment: Ответы-ссылки, не самая хорошая вещь. Ссылка может перестать работать и ваш ответ будет бесполезным. Перенесите основную информацию сюда, а ссылку оставьте как дополнительный источник.

Comment: Каким образом я через медиа запросы подключу js файл?!